# Converting from javax.json.JsonArray to org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java, org.json, javax.json

Is it possible to convert from the newer JSON libraries to the older org.json ones without having to rely on org.json.simple or GSON?

In the case below, "buttons" is a populated JsonArray and I'm trying to copy it into a JSONArray for legacy code. But the initialization of JSONArray from a stringified value always fails with "A JSONObject text must begin with '{'" because a quote is seen as a first character rather than a curly brace.

`JSONArray newButtons = new JSONArray(); for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) { JsonString button = buttons.getJsonString(i); newButtons.put(new JSONArray(button.toString())); } return new JSONArray(newButtons);`

It doesn't seem like there is any kind of org.json object that I can initialize from a string constructor with a toString() value from the javax.json library. I have managed to move data from org.json structures to javax.json ones, but not vice versa. Is the org.json library too inflexible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I believe following should work.

```java
JSONArray newButtons = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject button = buttons.getJsonObject(i);
    newButtons.put(new org.json.JSONObject(button.toString()));
}
return newButtons;
```

With the following line you get first the object with index 'i' and then make a JSON String out of it. Your original code rather returns the element 'i' as a value instead of an object.

```java
JsonString button = buttons.getJsonObject(i).toString();
```

Comment: I doubt that `toString()` returns a `JsonObject`.

Comment: If you're just going to stringify to JSON text, why not do it on the entire array, and be done with it without any loops?

Comment: true, I removed the 'toString()'. Thx for mentioning.